# Given $f:\mathbb R \backslash \{-1,0\} \to \mathbb R$, $f(x) = \frac{ |x \sin x| }{x + x^2}$: what values $c \in\mathbb R$ makes $f$ has limit.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, functions, continuity

I tried to demonstrate that is known that $x$, $sin x$, $x^2$ and $|x|$ are continuous functions. So the unique values that could not have limit are $c = -1$ or $c = 0$ but I cannot go on. Am I right?

Comment: Is the title suppose to say $f:\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0,-1\}\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x)=\frac{|x\sin x|}{x+x^2}$ etc.?

Comment: what limit do you want? for $x\to \infty$?

Comment: @saulspatz you are right I did not know how to wirte it sorry

Comment: @Exodd in the entire domine which elements has limit.

Comment: Apologies aren't necessary.  Here's a great MathJax [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: What exactly is $c$ here? It makes no appearance in the question other than to specify it's a real number.

Comment: @Decaf-Math you need to find every real $c$ that $lim_{x \to c} f(x)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I continued trying with this problem and I found out that $\lim_{x\to{0^+}}\frac{sin x}{1 + x}=0 $ and the same with $x \to 0^-$ where I changed the sign of the abs and it equals to $0$ to. So it remains to prove that exist $lim_{x \to -1 }  f(x)$.